# List all emailaddresses of users in pgadmin from terminal?

Tags: terminal, pgadmin

I cannot run this command, because I don't have the rights

```
select usesysid as user_id,
       usename as username,
       usesuper as is_superuser,
       passwd as password_md5,
       valuntil as password_expiration
from pg_shadow
order by usename;
```

But I was able to login in terminal to psql. How do I list there all emailaddresses of users in pgadmin from terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pgAdmin (web mode) login users are different from PostgreSQL server users. pgAdmin user details are stored in SQLite3 pgadmin4.db file. You can find the file //.pgadmin